# Web server is trying to access sql through sa user

Tags: sql-server

I am getting lot of message in sql audit logs on sql server as given below:

> my-web    Internet Information Services   sa  Audit Login Failed  130 Dec 9 2015 12:14PM
>
> my-web    Internet Information Services   sa  Audit Login Failed  92  Dec 9 2015 12:12PM

What I understand is web server is trying to connect sql server through `sa` user but we do not any app on web where user `sa` is defined in connection string.

I am unable to locate then why such weird message is coming in sql audit log, we have separate sql and web servers.

Comment: Is this an internal app, or is the web site open  to the internet?

Comment: @ Simon:  thanks for responding :---Its a webserver and the site is open to all. We have defined other user in the connection string to connect sql and can see in the logs that the defined user is connecting the sql sucessfully, just am confused from where web server is trying to connect sql server through user 'sa'

Comment: As a rule, right after I set up a new SQL Server instance, I create a new sysadmin user for myself, log in with that (to be sure it works), then assign a ridiculous password to the sa account and disable (not delete) it permanently. I have seen many attempts over the years at the sa login on various SQL boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

- You've been hacked and the hacker is trying access the db.
- The accesses come from somewhere internal to your network, not from the web server. Can Sql Server log the source IP and/or user?
- Check the Security Event Log on the db server for any events at the same time (e.g. Dec 9, 12:14). I logged onto a SQL Server with SQL logon (sa) from my workstation and there were three events recorded in the Security log. The first gave the workstation I was connecting from and the second gave the AD logon I was using.

Cheers -

Comment: Hello,                                                                                                                            I have checked the webserver and the sql server  there are not any invalid accounts further security events logs does not shows logon process of any account except the 3 accounts that we used to access the server .. can you please elaborate on how to find "The access come from somewhere internal to your network"                                                                 eagerly awaiting your response!!